# Hibernate: How to cascade embedded objects with parent object's auto-generated ID as a foreign key

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, one-to-one

**Question:**

In Hibernate (JPA 2.0), how can I create embedded objects with @OneToOne relationships when I create the parent object?

**Expectation:**

When I create a User, I expect it to automatically create the appropriate Properties with the User's auto-generated `id` as the Property's `object_id`.

**Reality:**

When I try to create a User, I get the following exception:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value: com.api.user.PropertyEntity.objectId
```

**Database Tables:**

I have two MySQL tables: `users` and `properties`

```
users
+----+----------+----------+
| id | username | password |
+----+----------+----------+
| 1  | foo      | bar      |
+----+----------+----------+
| 2  | goo      | baz      |
+----+----------+----------+
| 3  | woo      | hah      |
+----+----------+----------+

properties
+----+-----------+-------------+---------+-----------+
| id | object_id | object_type | propkey | propvalue |
+----+-----------+-------------+---------+-----------+
| 1  | 1         | user        | sso     | true      |
+----+-----------+-------------+---------+-----------+
| 2  | 1         | user        | ssoid   | foobar    |
+----+-----------+-------------+---------+-----------+
| 3  | 2         | user        | sso     | false     |
+----+-----------+-------------+---------+-----------+
| 4  | 2         | user        | ssoid   | null      |
+----+-----------+-------------+---------+-----------+
| 5  | 3         | user        | sso     | false     |
+----+-----------+-------------+---------+-----------+
| 6  | 3         | user        | ssoid   | null      |
+----+-----------+-------------+---------+-----------+
```

**Java Entities:**

A User can have multiple properties, but each property has a @OneToOne relationship with that User and the relationship is unidirectional (i.e. a User creates its Properties, not the other way around).

The `User` entity in Java looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class UserEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false)
    private String userName;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @OneToOne
    @Cascade(value = { org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE })
    @JoinColumnsOrFormulas(value={
            @JoinColumnOrFormula(column=
                   @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "object_id", insertable=false, updatable=false, nullable = false)
            ),
            @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula=
                    @JoinFormula(referencedColumnName="object_type", value="'user'")
            ),
            @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula=
                    @JoinFormula(referencedColumnName="propkey", value="'sso'")
            )
    })
    private PropertyEntity isSso;

    @OneToOne
    @Cascade(value = { org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE })
    @JoinColumnsOrFormulas(value={
            @JoinColumnOrFormula(column=
                    @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "object_id", insertable=false, updatable=false, nullable = false)
            ),
            @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula=
                    @JoinFormula(referencedColumnName="object_type", value="'user'")
            ),
            @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula=
                    @JoinFormula(referencedColumnName="propkey", value="'ssoid'")
            )
    })
    private PropertyEntity ssoId;

    // Getters & Setters
}
```

The `Property` entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "properties")
public class PropertyEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "object_id", nullable = false)
    private Integer objectId;

    @Column(name = "object_type", nullable = false)
    private String objectType;

    @Column(name = "propkey", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "propvalue", nullable = false)
    private String value;

    // Getters & Setters
}
```

Comment: Why can't you replace your PropertyEntity with a Map<String, String> on the User and store it as a `@MappedCollection` in your `PropertyEntity` table? That would take out all these headaches and is a cleaner design. Each User their own map of properties, and a map can never have duplicate keys. I know this may not seem helpful, but you appear to be trying to force Hibernate to do something that it's not designed to really do. Are you using the `PropertyEntity` elsewhere?

Comment: what "embedded" object? I see none. There is no @Embedded usage

Comment: @JamesMassey Thanks for your response! I started reading the docs on @MappedCollection, but got the impression that it might not work here. Maybe you could provide an example? I'm dealing with a legacy database and the `properties` table is used to store more than just `user` properties, hence the `object_type` column.

Comment: @NeilStockton I chose the word "embedded" to describe the fact that the `PropertyEntity` objects were contained within a `UserEntity` object, not being aware of the @Embedded annotation. Poor word choice, I guess. Sorry if that caused any confusion.

Answer (score -1):

Like most issues related to Hibernate annotations, I resolved this by eliminating them altogether and doing it the old fashioned way (making separate queries in my transaction for creating/updating a user and then creating/updating each user property record).

If anyone has a Hibernate solution that works, I'm happy to accept that answer.